# Chosing the right setup for stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, filtrations

Consider a stochastic process $Y_k:=x+k-(X_1+\dots +X_k)$ for $k=1,2,...$, where $x \in \mathbb{N} $ and $X_1$ are i.i.d. random variables which are integer valued and non negative.
The process starts at $Y_0=x$.
$P_x$ is the measure under the condition that $Y_0:=x$

Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{F},\mathcal{F}, P_x)$ a filtered probability space where $\mathbb{F}:= \{ \mathcal{F_k}: k \in \mathbb{N}\}$,  is the natural filtration generated by $X_k$, i.e. $\mathcal{F_k}= \sigma(X_s \mid s \leq k)$

Is $R_0 $ measurable, although my sigma-Algebra starts at $k=1$?

Since my process starts at $k=1$, I know  $R_0$ by computing $P_x(Y_k=s)$ for any $k=1,2,...$

Is this sufficient?

Comment: All you need is for your $X_{i}$'s to be measurable functions from $\Omega$ into the reals (integers here). Such functions do exist, as a probability space is a measurable space.

Comment: Are the $X_i$ measurable in $\mathbb{F}$

Comment: So you mean $X_1^{-1}(B)  \in \mathbb{F}$, where B is measurable,

Comment: What do I choose for the $\sigma$ algebra in $\mathbb{N}$ referring to $X_i : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I believe the $X_{i}$'s are $\mathcal{F}_{i}$-measurable, yes. Since you can write $X_{2} = Y_{2} - x - k - X_{1}$, and $X_{1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{1}$-measurable. You can then do this for any $k$.

Comment: @user7924249: Sorry for my late answer.  Why should $X_1$ be measurable? Maybe I can give my intuiton on that: I know $Y_n$, so I have to know $S_n$ and therefore I have to know $X_i$ for $i\leq n$

Comment: What $\sigma-$ algebra would I choose  in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I am honestly not sure about your intuition, since the parts of the sum are not uniquely determined from the value of the sum. Mathematically speaking, you have that $X_{1} = Y_{1} - x - k$, which is obviously measurable wrt. $\mathcal{F}_{1}$, as $x$ and $k$ are constants. Seeing as $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, I think you could even get away with choosing the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$ as your sigma-algebra. As far as I'm concerned, we don't generally bother too much with the sigma-algebras on discrete spaces, as all subsets of these are measurable.

Comment: Regarding your intuition: you know $Y_{1}$, $k$ and $x$, so you just isolate to obtain $X_{1}$. You then get that for general $Y_{k}$ you know $Y_{k}$, $S_{k-1}$, $k$ and $x$, and therefore you must also know $X_{k}$.

Comment: Ok perfect. Is it maybe better that the filtration is generated by $X_k$?

Comment: Then $x+k -(X_1+...+X_k)$ is measurable. and therefore $Y_k$?

Comment: Yes. I am quite confident (without having checked, but should not be hard), that the filtrations are the same, whether you generate with $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: So I have my filtered probabiliity space where the filtrations are generated by $X_k$. The $X_k$ map von $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{N}$ with the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$ to make it a measurable space.

Comment: By construction of $\mathbb{F}$ X_i are measurable.

Comment: Yes. That would be correct.

Comment: The last thing I am not sure. The sum of random variables is computed using convolution. Therefore $X_1+..+X_k$ is measurable in the product sigma algebra in general. Would this make a problem here? Maybe I mix something up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116570/discussion-between-user7924249-and-sarah).

Comment: @user7924249: If I consider the $X_1+...+X_N$, where N is an stochastic process. In that case Y shouldgenerate my filtration, isn't it

Comment: Sorry for the additional question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116689/discussion-between-sarah-and-user7924249).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are attempting to model.

For example, I've come across some stochastic processes where the paths have to be cadlag and the process predictable with regards to its underlying filtered sigma algebra.

**edit**

@Sarah; It sounds like your comments are along the right lines. I can't be more specific since its been about a decade since I've looked at this kind of material. I'd add though, that often the measure space is usually the Borel algebra of the space in question; that is one takes the minimal Borel algebra generated by the opens of the underlying topological space of the process in question.